# Spreading over a column in R

Tags: r, tidyr

So say I have a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,3,3,3),y = c(12,32,43,16,32,65))
```

and I want to transform it into a data frame like this:

```
data.frame(x = c(1, 3), y_1 =  c(12,16), y_2 =c(32, 32),y_3= c(43, 65))
```

basically spreading the y values for each unique x value. I've tried to do this using tidyr but can't quite see how it would work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dat = as.data.table(df) # or setDT to convert in place

dat[, obs := paste0('y_', 1:.N), by=x]
dcast(dat, x ~ obs, value.var="y")

#   x y_1 y_2 y_3
#1: 1  12  32  43
#2: 3  16  32  65
```

This will work even if the number of rows is not the same for all `x`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `aggregate`, and then `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` package to coerce to data frame,

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1 <- aggregate(y ~ x, df, paste, collapse = ',')
df1 <- cSplit(df1, 'y', ',', direction = 'wide')
#   x y_1 y_2 y_3
#1: 1  12  32  43
#2: 3  16  32  65
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Sotos using `aggregate` is particularly elegant, but the following approach using `reshape` might also be instructive:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,3,3,3),y = c(12,32,43,16,32,65))
df[,"time"] <- rep(1:3, 2)
wide_df <- reshape(df, direction="wide", timevar="time", idvar="x")
```

Comment: Nice one.  Could also plug in a `transform()` call and not have to alter the original data `reshape(transform(df, time=ave(y, x, FUN = seq_along)),
    direction = "wide", timevar = "time", idvar = "x", sep = "_")`

Answer (score 1):

One option with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(n = paste("y", row_number(), sep="_")) %>%
    spread(n,y)
#     x   y_1   y_2   y_3
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     1    12    32    43
#2     3    16    32    65
```